# The set of cyclic endomorphisms is open

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of matrices of size $n$ with real coefficients. Let $S$ denote the set of matrices $M$ in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that the minimal polynomial of $M$ equals the characteristic polynomial of $M$ (taking the definition of the characteristic polynomial to be $\det(xI-M)$).

Show that $S$ is an open subset of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify a matrix $A$ with the column vector $\widehat A=(a_{1,1},a_{1,2},\cdots, a_{1,n},a_{2,1},\cdots,a_{2,n},\cdots, a_{{n-1},n},a_{n,n})^t$.
Recall that $A^k$ is a matrix the entries of which are polynomials in the entries of $A$.

A $(n\times n)$ matrix is cyclic if and only if $\dim(I,A,\cdots, A^{n-1})=n$ or equivalently, under the identification above, if and only if $$\operatorname{rk}\begin{pmatrix}\widehat I&\widehat {A}&\widehat {A^2}&\cdots&\widehat {A^{n-1}}\end{pmatrix}=n$$

Since the matrix of which we are considering the rank - henceforth called $\mathcal M(A)$ - is of size $(n^2\times n)$ (and $n\le n^2$) this is equivalent to requiring that $\operatorname{rk}\mathcal M(A)\ge n$. This is the case if and only if at least one of the $\binom{n^2}n$ submatrices of size $(n\times n)$ of $\mathcal M(A)$ has non-zero determinant. Since all the entries of $\mathcal M(A)$ are polynomials in the entries of $A$, this results in the logical "or" of $\binom {n^2}{n}$ equations of the form $p_h(a_{1,1},a_{1,2}\cdots,a_{n-1,n}, a_{n,n})\ne 0$ for some polynomial $p_h$. This identifies an open subset of $\Bbb R^{n^2}=M_n(\Bbb R)$.

This argument, paired with the observation that some matrices are actually cyclic, proves that the set is dense as well.

**Added:** To set up the smallest non-trivial instance of this procedure, when $n=3$ we are imposing the condition $$\operatorname{rk}\begin{pmatrix}1&a_{11}&a_{11}^2+a_{12}a_{21}+a_{13}a_{31}\\ 0&a_{12}& a_{11}a_{12}+a_{12}a_{22}+a_{13}a_{32}\\ 0&a_{13}&a_{11}a_{13}+a_{12}a_{23}+a_{13}a_{33}\\0 &a_{21}&a_{21}a_{11}+a_{22}a_{21}+a_{23}a_{31}\\ 1&a_{22}&a_{21}a_{12}+a^2_{22}+a_{23}a_{32}\\0&a_{23}& a_{21}a_{13}+a_{22}a_{32}+a_{23}a_{33}\\ 0& a_{31}&a_{31}a_{11}+a_{32}a_{21}+a_{33}a_{31}\\ 0&a_{32}&a_{31}a_{12}+a_{32}a_{22}+a_{33}a_{32}\\ 1&a_{33}&a_{31}a_{13}+a_{32}a_{23}+a_{33}^2\end{pmatrix}=3$$

The matrices that satisfy it are the ones in the set \begin{align}&\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}\,:\, \det\begin{pmatrix}1&a_{11}&a_{11}^2+a_{12}a_{21}+a_{13}a_{31}\\ 0&a_{12}& a_{11}a_{12}+a_{12}a_{22}+a_{13}a_{32}\\ 0&a_{13}&a_{11}a_{13}+a_{12}a_{23}+a_{13}a_{33}\end{pmatrix}\ne0\right\}\\\cup&\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}\,:\, \det\begin{pmatrix}1&a_{11}&a_{11}^2+a_{12}a_{21}+a_{13}a_{31}\\ 0&a_{12}& a_{11}a_{12}+a_{12}a_{22}+a_{13}a_{32}\\ 0 &a_{21}&a_{21}a_{11}+a_{22}a_{21}+a_{23}a_{31}\end{pmatrix}\ne0\right\}\\\cup&\cdots\end{align} And all those determinants are the polynomials $p_1,p_2,\cdots$ I was referring to. Since there are $84$ (actually $64$, because $20$ of them are trivially the zero polynomial), I'll pass wirting them.

Comment: This is very beautiful. I will just clarify some details for the end of your argum ent.  I guess you reasoned as follows: Given a polynomial $P$ in $n$ variables with real coefficients, P defines a continuous map $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}-{0}$ is open, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}-{0})$ is open. We may conclude since a union of open sets is open.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou Yes, of course.

Comment: Also, there is another argument which is slightly simpler: $A$ cyclic implies $I,A,...,A^{n-1}$ is linearly independent, as you noted. Hence we may complete this set into a basis of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ by adding some vectors $E_{n+1},..,E_{n^2}$. Now let $B$ be the canonical basis of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and define $\phi(N)=det_B(I,N...,N^{n-1},E_{n+1},..,E_{n^2})$. Then $\phi$ defines a continuous map from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi(A) \neq 0$. Hence for $N$ sufficiently close to $A$, $\phi(N) \neq 0$, so $I,N,...,N^{n-1}$ is linearly independent, so $N$ is cyclic.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou Ah, ok. I see now, nevermind.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't see the simple reason why this argument works to prove cyclic matrices are dense.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou It is true in general that the locus of zeros of a non-zero polynomial in $n$ variables has empty interior in the eucidean topology of $\Bbb R^n$ (or $\Bbb C^n$). And this is the union of complements of such things.

Comment: this is what I had in mind, but this fact is not so obvious so I thought you were alluding to some very simple argument.

Answer (score 0):

Remark that the characterestic and minimal polynomials of $A$ coincide if and only if there is some non-zero vector $x$ such that $x,A^{1}x \cdots A^{n-1}x$ is a basis, which is equivalent to saying that the matrix whose columns are $x,A^{1}x \cdots A^{n-1}x$  is invertible, Now the result follows from the openness of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, Since if $B$ is close enough to $A$, the matrix whose columns are $x,B^{1}x \cdots B^{n-1}x$ would be close enough to the matrix whose columns are $x,A^{1}x \cdots A^{n-1}x $.Hence the matrix associated to $B$ would be invertible,i.e the characterestic and minimal polynomials of $B$ coincide .